# jQuery attr("src") returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to grab the source of an image using jQuery. However, when I log the result, it returns undefined. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-expand").on("click", function() {
    var img = $(".img-" + "num" + " img").attr("src");
    console.log(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 img-banner img-2">
    <img src="assets/img/placeholder-banner.png" alt="Banner 2">
    <div class="overlay overlay-2">
      <div class="overlay-contents">
        <h2>Name2</h2>
        <h3>Caption2</h3>
        <a href="" class="btn-expand" overlay-data="2">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is the selector in 3 parts? `".img-" + "num" + " img"` Were you intending `num` to be a variable defined somewhere?

Comment: $(".img-" + "num" + " img") here you are looking for element which is not present in your HTML

Comment: Attribute `overlay-data="2"` should be reworked as `data-overlay="2"` Then you can use `this.dataset.overlay` to get its value.

Comment: ...also, if that's a consistent DOM structure, you can get the related image with: `$(this).closest(".overlay").prev()` or `this.closest(".overlay").previousElementSibling`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".img-" + "num" + " img")
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
$(".img-num img")
```

I believe you meant `"num"` to be a variable called `num` whose value is the number of the target image, not a hard-coded string:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-expand").on("click", function(event) {
    var num = $(event.currentTarget).attr('overlay-data')
    var img = $(".img-" + num + " img").attr("src");
    console.log(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 img-banner img-2">
    <img src="assets/img/placeholder-banner.png" alt="Banner 2">
    <div class="overlay overlay-2">
      <div class="overlay-contents">
        <h2>Name2</h2>
        <h3>Caption2</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn-expand" overlay-data="2">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't see that! I was staring at the code for half an hour and couldn't figure out what was wrong!

Comment: @NicholasChan No problem, good sir. I actually had a good friend that would always do this same thing. Oh, and I totally second the motion by @rockstar and @epascarello that `overlay-data` should be `data-overlay` for best browser support. Then access it with `$(event.currentTarget).data('overlay')`

Answer (score 4):

Well you have an attribute on the anchor you do not read. Change it to be a data attribute and use a variable instead of hardcoding a string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-expand").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var overlay = $(this).data("overlay")
    var img = $(".img-" + overlay + " img").attr("src");
    console.log(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 img-banner img-2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Banner 2">
    <div class="overlay overlay-2">
      <div class="overlay-contents">
        <h2>Name2</h2>
        <h3>Caption2</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn-expand" data-overlay="2">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything looks good except that the attribute value wasn't defined. To set an attribute in jQuery, you must set the value. Hence, to correct that snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-expand").on("click", function(event) {
    var num = $(event.currentTarget).attr('overlay-data')
    var img = $(".img-" + num + " img").attr("src");
    console.log(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 img-banner img-2">
    <img src="assets/img/placeholder-banner.png" alt="Banner 2">
    <div class="overlay overlay-2">
      <div class="overlay-contents">
        <h2>Name2</h2>
        <h3>Caption2</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn-expand" overlay-data="2">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-expand").on("click", function(event) {
    var num = $(event.currentTarget).attr('overlay-data')
    var img = $(".img-" + num + " img").attr("src","imageSource.extention");
    console.log(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 img-banner img-2">
    <img src="assets/img/placeholder-banner.png" alt="Banner 2">
    <div class="overlay overlay-2">
      <div class="overlay-contents">
        <h2>Name2</h2>
        <h3>Caption2</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn-expand" overlay-data="2">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var img = $(".img-" + "num" + " img").attr("src");
```

in this code you are looking for tag with class `"im-num"` and child with class `"img"`. if you give class `im-num` to outer `div` and class `img`  like below

```
<div class="col-md-12 img-banner img-2 im-num">
     <img src="assets/img/placeholder-banner.png" alt="Banner 2" class='img'/>
</div>
```